# React native - Implement screen mirroring

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to create an app, which would connect into external android screen (using wifi), and mirror the whole app into it (I'd like to have control over the app by using the external screen)

Searched for possible solutions (libraries, protocols, dlna etc..), but nothing seems to suit for this case.

Any suggentions of how to implement it?

That's what I wanna get (one phone is good enough, "protake" app video mirroring)
[image: "protake" app video mirroring]